# How can I downgrade/compile Python in Termux?

Tags: python, downgrade, termux

I started using `termux` 1-2 weeks ago and I'm in love with it. Funnily, the first days in, everything worked fine and then a Python update hit, and I can no longer use my Python plugins in Neovim. It requres v3.9 or earlier.

I tried searching online and asking in Termux discord about how to downgrade Python to v3.9 or how to fix this but got nothing so far.

I would appreciate it if someone could tell me a solution or point me in a better direction about fixing the issue on my own.

Comment: Have you read this topic? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54875168/how-to-install-specific-python-version-termux

Comment: Yes, I only have 3.10 in cache bcz I reinstalled termux from f-droid while I was unnaware of this issue. So my chache is gone.